# Resample array from high resolution to low

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, python-2.7, scipy

I have an issue that I have not been able to solve correctly using scipy. I would like to 
resample and array such that I reduce the resolution (going from higher to lower) but, and here's where things get problematic, the new array shape is not a factor of the old one.
For example:

```
 lat = scipy.mgrid[-14.0:14+0.25:0.25]
 lon = scipy.mgrid[100.0:300+0.25:0.25]
 z = rand((lat.shape[0],lon.shape[0]))
 new_res = 0.70135
```

Now I have an array z with a spatial resolution of 0.25 and I want to decrease this to new_res. any ideas how this can be done using scipy or by hand? A futher complication is that bad data will often exist in the array z, i.e., z[0.20] might be nan.

Appreciate your help and thoughts

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to do this is to use [`scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html#scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates).

```
lat = scipy.mgrid[-14.0:14+0.25:0.25]
lon = scipy.mgrid[100.0:300+0.25:0.25]
z = tile(lon,(len(lat),1))
new_res = 0.70135


new_lat = scipy.mgrid[-14.0:14+0.25:new_res]
new_lon = scipy.mgrid[100.0:300+0.25:new_res]
X,Y = meshgrid(((new_lat-np.min(lat))/(np.max(lat)-np.min(lat)))*lat.shape[0],((new_lon-np.min(lon))/(np.max(lon)-np.min(lon)))*lon.shape[0])
pts = np.asarray(zip(X.ravel(),Y.ravel())).T
new_z = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates(z,pts).reshape(len(new_lon),len(new_lat)).T
```

All of that mess in the `meshgrid` call is to convert real units -> array units.  I am not sure how this will deal with `NaN`, I suspect you will have to clean the data first or accept the regions of `NaN` growing when you re-sample.

This [tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) might also be useful.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code. There are many things there that I don't understand - not as advance a python programmer. I would like to avoid any interpolation of the data as much as possible. I'll test this code and see. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to down-sample you data is any way other than simply summing squares of pixels then you _must_ do some interpolation.  There is some issues with differences of axes conventions that makes this code more complicated than strictly necessary.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried summing the squares but this leads to more complicated methods and code. I tried your method and the results becomes too noisy and erroneous in places. I think this is because the data type is very digital.

Comment: @Shejo284 Try setting the order to 1.  The default order is 3, which can give you huge artifacts if the there are sharp edges.  `map_coordinates(z,pts,order=1)`